# Image over an image using a class (CSS)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The problem I have here is because we use a theme (wordpress) for our clients that makes it easy for them to change an image and this is a simple version of the code it produces:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
      <img class="image" src="image user can change">
   </div>
</div>
```

What I need to try and achieve is a layer over the top of the image to put a logo on the image without changing the core HTML that the theme produces and only using CSS.

My thought was adding a background image to the class column and somehow bringing it in front. I tried z-index on the column with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo-elements to achieve what you are after. Try using something like the following code:

```
.column {
  position:relative;
}
.column:after {
  content:"";  
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  background:url(your-image.jpg); 
}
.column img {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Here is an example fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/scooterlord/cqhf2gw4/

Answer (score 1):

I think you could take advantage of the `:after` selector in your column class. Something like this:

```
.column {
    position: relative;
}

.column:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background-image: url('path/to/logo.png');
}
```

That would position a small logo in the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

Add new class `.overlay` add the `img` logo path, give the parent `position:absolute;`

```css
.image {
height: 200px;
max-width: 100%;
}

.overlay{
position:absolute;
/*positioning here*/
}

.overlay img{
height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
   <div class="overlay"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a"></div>
      <img class="image" src="https://d4n5pyzr6ibrc.cloudfront.net/media/27FB7F0C-9885-42A6-9E0C19C35242B5AC/4785B1C2-8734-405D-96DC23A6A32F256B/thul-90efb785-97af-5e51-94cf-503fc81b6940.jpg?response-content-disposition=inline">
   </div>
</div>
```